# Scope variables and functions in R

Tags: r, function, scope

I have the following data:

```
trials <- data.frame(
  full_condition  = rep(c("condition1", "condition2", "condition3"), times = 3),
  participant_md5 = rep(c("participant1", "participant2", "participant3"), each = 3),
  score.ordinal   = sample(as.ordered(1:7), 9, replace = TRUE)
)

# > head(trials)
# full_condition participant_md5 score.ordinal
# 1 condition1     participant1    2            
# 2 condition2     participant1    4            
# 3 condition3     participant1    3            
# 4 condition1     participant2    1
```

I want to compare scores across pairs of conditions (e.g. *condition1* vs *condition2*). The following code achieves that:

```
subtrials <- subset(trials, full_condition %in% c("condition1", "condition2"))
model.null <- clmm(score_ordinal ~ 1 + (1 | participant_md5), data = subtrials)
model <- clmm(score_ordinal ~ full_condition + (1 | participant_md5), data = subtrials)

anova(model, model.null)
```

Now, I want to make the comparison into a function called `two.sample.paired.ordinal` so that I can compare different pairs of condition (say *condition2* and *condition3*):

```
condition2vs3 <- two.sample.paired.ordinal(subset(trials, full_condition %in% c("condition2",  "condition3")))
```

I tried:

```
two.sample.paired.ordinal <- function(subtrials) {
    model_dep1  <- clmm(score_ordinal ~ full_condition + (1 | participant_md5), data = subtrials)
    model_null1 <- clmm(score_ordinal ~ 1              + (1 | participant_md5), data = subtrials)

    to.return <- anova(model_dep1, model_null1)
    return(to.return)
}
```

But when I run:

```
two.sample.paired.ordinal(subset(trials, full_condition %in% c("condition1",  "condition2")))
two.sample.paired.ordinal(subset(trials, full_condition %in% c("condition2", "condition3")))
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in anova.clmm(model_null1, model_dep1): Unable to evaluate models.
```

The function only works when `model_null1` and `model_dep1` are defined in the global context but then the function performs `anova` on the models that have these names in the global context.

**Question:** Why can't `anova` seem to access the locally defined `model_null1` and `model_dep1`? How can I create the desired function?

Comment: You might add a `browser()` call above `to.return <-` and run your function, then check what these values are. It did already certainly evaluate `model_null1` or it wouldn't have known how to use the "clmm" method of `anova()`. To help you more it'd be convenient to have a reproducible example

Comment: As you do not provide the data or a minimal workign example, we can oly guess. `anova()` only works for nested models, so maybe one of your subsets has a varaible that is constant and thus cannot be used as a predictor?

Comment: Thanks to both! I added code to generate a data frame of the right form to the question. To reproduce, just run all the code cells in the question in the order presented. `browse()` shows that indeed the clmm are evaluated as they are outside the function. Because of this, I think it's not that the subsets have constant values for any of the columns and inspection of the subsets confirm this as well.